# How to get SQL Query on model->save() in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I view the SQL Query on model->save() in CakePHP 3? Is there any way to do this? I want to get the specific sql query e.g when I save new entity.

I need it because I want to save that to a log file in some cases.

My bootstrap.php log config:

```
Log::config('current', [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => LOGS.DS.date('Y-m').DS,
    'scopes' => ['daily','queriesLog'],
    'file' => date('Y-m-d'),
]);
```

What i want to get:

e.g when i save entity:

```
$this->Clients->save($client);
```

i want to log something and i want to save INSERT sql query with this log

```
Log::warning('test\n', ['scope' => ['daily']]);
```

Comment: Here do you want to view the query?which is executed before save of a new entity?

Comment: I want to see the query of INSERT and UPDATE action when model->save().

Comment: I have posted an answer please check it,is it required or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution could be using query logging

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging

you can turn query logging on just when you save your model and then turn it off

For example I have a Comments model

In my bootstrap.php I did

```
Log::config('current', 
[ 
    'className' => 'File', 
    'path' => LOGS.date('Y-m').DS, // you don't need a DS between LOGS and date()
    'scopes' => ['daily','queriesLog'], 
    'file' => date('Y-m-d'), 
]);
```

and in my controller I did

```
$conn = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
$comment = $this->Comments->get(5620); // 5620 is the id of one comments of mine
$conn->logQueries(true);
$comment = $this->Comments->get(5619); // 5619 is onother id of one comments of mine
$comment->text = 'Test';
$this->Comments->save($comment);
$conn->logQueries(false);
```

In this way a file is created in the logs folder and the file contains the following

```
2015-12-16 13:38:35 Debug: SELECT ... WHERE Comments.id = 5619 LIMIT 1
2015-12-16 13:38:35 Debug: BEGIN
2015-12-16 13:38:35 Debug: UPDATE comments SET text = 'Test' WHERE id = 5619
2015-12-16 13:38:35 Debug: COMMIT
```

note that the query used to get comment #5620 has not been logged

Also note that this works if you don't have debugkit enabled

Comment: Well yeah i saw that solution, but it saves whole sql that is creating when the page render. But i need to get specific query for some actions and not only in debug mode.

Comment: I need something like this $log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);  That was in Cakephp 2

Comment: you can turn logging on just before calling model->save. And it works when debug mode is off

Comment: I set the query logging to true before model->save() but that doesn't do anything. I set my config like this: Log::config('current', [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => LOGS.DS.date('Y-m').DS,
    'scopes' => ['daily','queriesLog'],
    'file' => date('Y-m-d'),
]);

Comment: I tested your code and it worked (it actually created the folder with the date and the log file in it). I also noted that if I have debugKit enabled it captures the queries so that nothing is sent to the logger.

Comment: Yes it created the folder and file but it doesnt put the query if i set $conn->logQueries(true); before model save.

Comment: Try editing your question posting your actual code, because I did a little test and it worked

Comment: Done that, please check :)

Comment: Thanks its working! but i needed to set 'log' => true in app.php and $conn->logQueries(false) in appcontroller because in other way i didint get anything saved to file log. :) great thank u

Comment: well, it should work in the other way, too. Hope someone else will come here and help you solve this issue

Comment: setConfig() should be used instead of config() in newer versions of Cake.

Answer (score -2):

Put this into model

```html
 function getLastQuery() {
        Configure::write(‘debug’,false);
        $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
        $logs = $dbo->getLog();
        $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
        $latQuery = $lastLog['query'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($latQuery);
    }
```

```
after $this->save($data);
```

call that function

```html
$this->getLastQuery();
```

and echo it.

Try it.

Comment: Isn't this for cake 2.* ? getDatasource() and getLog() functions doesn't exist in cakephp 3 right?

Comment: It's not working with your code i get undefined method getDatasource(), but i edited your code to make it cakephp 3 ready         $dbo = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $logs = $dbo->getLog();
        $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
        $latQuery = $lastLog['query'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($latQuery);  But now it says that "Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Connection::getLog()"

Comment: CakePHP 3: Simplest way is to print $model->sql()