# get raw sql query from ORM save cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I havea working cakephp 3.x app. Now I have to save information coming from web forms to 2 databases. One is the local app database, the other is a database on a remote server. When the internet connection to the remote server is not working, I need to save the query and attempt to run it later, when internet connection is back.

To achieve this I want to get the raw sql query from `$this->model->save($entity)` calls, save them in a special table in the local database. However, I can't seem to find a way to get the raw sql from cakephp ORM. How can it be done?

Comment: Why not re-run the code when the internet connection goes back online?

Comment: The code uses form input data, which is not sanitized, not a simple string. I figured it's easier to get the sql query generated by cakephp. If only I can find a way to expose it to my controller.

Comment: What about storing the input, sanitising it and re-run the code? To me, this makes more sense than to store the query.  If you're really want to get the query, this will help you further. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34292797/1604068